# Swift: UIPageViewController - Navigate view controllers with swipe from edge of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to `UIPageViewControllers` and can't seem to find a solution elsewhere. I have a working `UIPageViewController` with 3 different `viewControllers`. Right now you can navigate to a different `viewController` by swiping left or right starting at any point on the screen. However, I only want to navigate to a different `viewController` when I swipe over from the right or left edge of the screen. Similar to how the `Screen Edge Pan Gesture` works. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about implementing this in my program.

Comment: Page type or scroll type?

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this situation is to attach gesture recognizers to the views of the "3 different viewControllers", that is, the child view controllers of the page view controller. These gesture recognizers' action methods post notifications. In the view controller that controls the page view controller, I receive these notifications and call `setViewControllers:direction:animated:` to perform the appropriate slide.

Comment: Downloadable example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController/AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score -2):

`UIPageViewController` has and embedded gesture recognizers that to the trick. Normally you have no influence on them. You could get to them by calling `gestureRecognizers` method on `UIPageViewController`'s view and see what you can do with them from there.

Comment: I have been looking through apple documentation on `gestureRecognizers` for `UIPageViewControllers` but I can't find anything on altering these except disabling them.

Comment: Yeah, well, then it means that this element doesn't differ much from other default elements, which means that you can't customize it, basically.